# How to call a function using if statement and then print the value inside the function

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

I'm new to C programming language and when I'm practicing using struct, I cannot print the struct value inside a function using an if statement, it prints the memory address(I think). But when I tried to call the function without an if statement it works just fine.
This is the code using an if statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
    int age[10];
    int input;
}data;

int inputData(){
    data inputData;
    int i;
    printf("Total Data :");
    scanf("%d", &inputData.input);
    for(i=1;i<=inputData.input;i++){
        printf("Input your age :");
        scanf("%d", &inputData.age[i]);
    }
    return main();
}

void viewData(){
    data viewData;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=viewData.input;i++){
        printf("%d", viewData.age[i]);
    }
    
}
int main(){
    int menu;
    printf("Input menu :");
    scanf("%d", &menu);
    if(menu==1){
        inputData();
    }else if(menu==2){
        viewData();
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
Input menu :1
Total Data :2
Input your age :21
Input your age :31
Input menu :2
0853839645327661046072584004611648742404199977042107010648742008541535363276664803040725840046264875200419984104210701064874800854153536327666480368002131327661046
```

However when I delete the return main() inside the **inputData** function and change the **int main** to:

```
int main(){
    inputData();
    viewData();
}
```

It works just fine. Output:

```
Total Data :2
Input your age :21
Input your age :31
2131
```

Please help me to find a way to make the if statement code works. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Arrays are zero based: `for(i=1;i<=inputData.input;i++){` --> `for(i=0;i<inputData.input;i++){`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you

Note: in C language ,loops start from 0 to length of array -1

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct data
{
    int age[10];
    int input;
}data;

void inputData()
{
    data inputData;
    printf("Total Data :");
    scanf("%d",&inputData.input);

    for(int i=0;i<inputData.input;i++)
    {
         printf("Input your age :");
         scanf("%d", &inputData.age[i]);
    }
}

void viewData()
{
    data viewData;
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0;i<viewData.input;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", viewData.age[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int menu;
    do
    {
         printf("Input menu :");
         scanf("%d",&menu);
    }while(menu!=1);

    switch(menu)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            inputData();
        }
        case 2:
        {
            viewData();
        }break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do just `return;` and the function declaration should be

```
void inputData( void )
```

By doing `return main();` you are creating a recursive loop where `main` calls `inputData` and `inputData` calls `main`